# How to create ScrollView to cover 2 TableLayout?

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

[image: Outline]

I know that ScrollView can have only one Child but in my case I need to have 2 TableLayout That use the same scroll. I did tried using LayoutView wrap 2 TableLayout inside like below sample... but it show only the view in the first TableLayout

```
   <ScrollView 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <TableLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               //...
           </TableLayout>
           <TableLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               //...
           </TableLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want a vertically scrolling list. Wrapping the two tables should work but LinearLayout defaults to horizontal orientation. So add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the wrapping LinearLayout

Comment: @AliSh at frist i try to accept but there is an alert dialog that "You can accept this question after 9 minutes" so i go out for dinner sorry.. for late accept